# Retrieving columns from data frames which are dict items in python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, dataframe

I need to create code able to read in multiple csv files, look for commonly titled columns among the files, and extract them in an array. I'm filling a python dictionary with .csv files imported as data frames in order to be able to call on them in a for loop. However, I don't really know what the for loop to pull columns from each item of a dict would look like. Here is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

r= int(input('How many files do you want to plot?: '))
l= range(r) 
d={}
for i in l:
    inp= str(input('Type name of file #'+str(i+1)+': '))
    d[i]= pd.read_csv(inp, sep=',') #fills dict with dataframes

print(d) ##prints dict to visually check for errors
```

Then, I need to name the column which I need to extract:

```
freq= input('Which frequency would you like to plot at?: ') ##The desired shared column (labeled by a common string) among the dataframes
```

After this, I'm stuck. I can only think to create a for loop which iterates over each dict item, "scans across" the first row to find the title string, and then takes that column, but I don't know how to code that. Any tips???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a dictionary of dataframes `d`, you can extract a column (or `pd.Series`) from each dataframe as follows:

```
freq = input('Which frequency would you like to plot at?: ')
series = {k: v[freq] for k, v in d.items()}
```

This will create a dictionary of columns named `freq`. The manipulation you require next is not clear from your question. You may need to concatenate them, or perform some calculation for your desired output.